# Receive Data from android application in asp.net page

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net, .net

In my project I've a requirement in which I want to receive data in page load event of my asp.net application page sent by an android application. I've been through all the concepts over internet but unable to find the proper answers or any kind of code. Moreover, I also want to know that is the question I've asked it is Programmatically possible.

**Note**: Our Android Application also uses WebView feature of android, and displays an aspx page.

Comment: yes. give url i provide code.

Comment: Thanks for your Response @Android Team , Can you share any kind of code or link with me regarding the same scenario.